# ERROR TypeError: data.sort is not a function

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using Angular material version 8.0.3. I get the following error when i load the component.

```
ERROR TypeError: data.sort is not a function
    at MatTableDataSource.sortData (table.js:466)
    at MatTableDataSource._orderData (table.js:684)
    at MapSubscriber.project (table.js:633)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:29)
    at MapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at CombineLatestSubscriber.notifyNext (combineLatest.js:73)
    at InnerSubscriber._next (InnerSubscriber.js:11)
    at InnerSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.js:69)
    at InnerSubscriber._next (InnerSubscriber.js:11)
```

Following is the code snippet:

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort


ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.dataList);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
}
```

Comment: Can you post html code as well. It will be even better if you can make a stackblitz

Comment: I deleted "this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;" lines... And it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.dataList);    
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort


ngOnInit() {
this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
}
```

`this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.dataList);`

should be outside ngOnInit and this.dataSource should be only

```
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.dataList);
```

Comment: Are you getting the same error ...or something else ?

Comment: this: typeof globalThis
Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.

Comment: I have updated my answer and still if it doesn't work can you please post entire code or create a stackblitz